# Received an "expected expression error " when i added a function

Tags: c

Im trying to write a program that wont compile. The error i keep receiving reads like this

expected expression
destroyFallingStone (int map[][SIZE], int column);

It happened after i added the destroyFallingStone function and Ive checked the function and function prototype for any syntax errors. I don't know where Ive made a mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 15
#define EMPTY 0
#define STONE 1

// TODO: Add any extra #defines here.

// TODO: Add any extra function prototypes here.

void printMap(int map[SIZE][SIZE], int playerX);

void destroyFallingStone (int map[][SIZE], int column);

int main (void) {
    // This line creates our 2D array called "map" and sets all
    // of the blocks in the map to EMPTY.
    int map[SIZE][SIZE] = {EMPTY};

    // This line creates out playerX variable. The player starts in the
    // middle of the map, at position 7.
    int playerX = SIZE / 2;

    printf("How many lines of stone? ");
    // TODO: Scan in the number of lines of blocks.
    int linesOfStone; 
    scanf("%d", &linesOfStone);

    printf("Enter lines of stone:\n");
    // TODO: Scan in the lines of blocks.
    
    int rowPos; 
    int columnPos; 
    int stoneLength; 
    int stoneValue; 
   
    int i = 0; 
    while (i < linesOfStone) {
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &rowPos, &columnPos, &stoneLength, &stoneValue);
        
        if ( 0 <= rowPos && rowPos < SIZE && 
             0 <= columnPos && columnPos < SIZE
             && columnPos + stoneLength - 1 < SIZE) { 
            int j = 0; 
            while (j < stoneLength) { 
                map[rowPos][columnPos + j] = STONE; 
                j++; 
            }
        }
        i++; 
    }

    printMap(map, playerX);

    // TODO: Scan in commands until EOF.
    // After each command is processed, you should call printMap.
    
  
    int quitLoop = 0; 
    int playerDirection = 0; 
    int playerMovement = 0; 
    
    while (quitLoop != 1) {
    scanf("%d %d", &playerMovement, &playerDirection); 
        if ( playerMovement == 1 && 
            playerDirection == 1 && playerX < (SIZE - 1)) { 
        //check player is within bounds 
        playerX++; 
        } else if ( playerMovement == 1 && 
                   playerDirection == -1 && playerX > 0 ) {
        playerX--;
        } else if ( playerMovement == 2) { // call function for destroying stones 
            destroyFallingStone (int map[][SIZE], int column);
        }
    
    printMap(map, playerX);
    } 
   

    return 0;
}

// Print out the contents of the map array. Then print out the player line
// which will depends on the playerX variable.
void printMap(int map[SIZE][SIZE], int playerX) {
    
    // Print values from the map array.
    int i = 0;
    while (i < SIZE) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < SIZE) {
            printf("%d ", map[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }    
    
    // Print the player line.
    i = 0;
    while (i < playerX) {
        printf("  ");
        i++;
    }
    printf("P\n");
}

//destroys the closes 2 stones 
void destroyFallingStone (int map[][SIZE], int column) {

    int i = 0;  
    int j = 0; 

    while (j < 3) {
        while (i < 15 && map[i][column] != STONE) { //finding the first stone 
            i++; 
        }
        // if there is a stone, destroy it 
        if (map[i][column] == STONE) {
            map[i][column] = EMPTY;
        }    
        i++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you call the function, you don't need the types: `destroyFallingStone (int map[][SIZE], int column);` => `destroyFallingStone (map, column);`  (similar to how you call `printMap`).

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the function correctly:

```
    } else if ( playerMovement == 2) { // call function for destroying stones 
        destroyFallingStone (int map[][SIZE], int column);
    }
```

What you have here looks more like a declaration than a function call.  You instead want:

```
    } else if ( playerMovement == 2) { // call function for destroying stones 
        destroyFallingStone(map,column);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in line: 75 `destroyFallingStone (int map[][SIZE], int column);`. This should be a call to function `destroyFallingStone`. Something like `destroyFallingStone (map, columnPos);`.

Following is corrected code. See [it compiling here](https://ideone.com/GtLrgf):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 15
#define EMPTY 0
#define STONE 1

// TODO: Add any extra #defines here.

// TODO: Add any extra function prototypes here.

void printMap(int map[SIZE][SIZE], int playerX);

void destroyFallingStone (int map[][SIZE], int column);

int main (void) {
    // This line creates our 2D array called "map" and sets all
    // of the blocks in the map to EMPTY.
    int map[SIZE][SIZE] = {EMPTY};

    // This line creates out playerX variable. The player starts in the
    // middle of the map, at position 7.
    int playerX = SIZE / 2;

    printf("How many lines of stone? ");
    // TODO: Scan in the number of lines of blocks.
    int linesOfStone; 
    scanf("%d", &linesOfStone);

    printf("Enter lines of stone:\n");
    // TODO: Scan in the lines of blocks.
    
    int rowPos; 
    int columnPos; 
    int stoneLength; 
    int stoneValue; 
   
    int i = 0; 
    while (i < linesOfStone) {
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &rowPos, &columnPos, &stoneLength, &stoneValue);
        
        if ( 0 <= rowPos && rowPos < SIZE && 
             0 <= columnPos && columnPos < SIZE
             && columnPos + stoneLength - 1 < SIZE) { 
            int j = 0; 
            while (j < stoneLength) { 
                map[rowPos][columnPos + j] = STONE; 
                j++; 
            }
        }
        i++; 
    }

    printMap(map, playerX);

    // TODO: Scan in commands until EOF.
    // After each command is processed, you should call printMap.
    
  
    int quitLoop = 0; 
    int playerDirection = 0; 
    int playerMovement = 0; 
    
    while (quitLoop != 1) {
    scanf("%d %d", &playerMovement, &playerDirection); 
        if ( playerMovement == 1 && 
            playerDirection == 1 && playerX < (SIZE - 1)) { 
        //check player is within bounds 
        playerX++; 
        } else if ( playerMovement == 1 && 
                   playerDirection == -1 && playerX > 0 ) {
        playerX--;
        } else if ( playerMovement == 2) { // call function for destroying stones 
            destroyFallingStone (map, columnPos);
        }
    
    printMap(map, playerX);
    } 
   

    return 0;
}

// Print out the contents of the map array. Then print out the player line
// which will depends on the playerX variable.
void printMap(int map[SIZE][SIZE], int playerX) {
    
    // Print values from the map array.
    int i = 0;
    while (i < SIZE) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < SIZE) {
            printf("%d ", map[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }    
    
    // Print the player line.
    i = 0;
    while (i < playerX) {
        printf("  ");
        i++;
    }
    printf("P\n");
}

//destroys the closes 2 stones 
void destroyFallingStone (int map[][SIZE], int column) {

    int i = 0;  
    int j = 0; 

    while (j < 3) {
        while (i < 15 && map[i][column] != STONE) { //finding the first stone 
            i++; 
        }
        // if there is a stone, destroy it 
        if (map[i][column] == STONE) {
            map[i][column] = EMPTY;
        }    
        i++; 
    }
}
```